# How to view Garbage collector logs in android logcat

Tags: android, garbage-collection, logcat

I need to view the Garbage Collector messages in logcat for the device. I dont get any messages with dalvik-vm tag in my logcat, when I am testing my app on device. But I get these messages when I am using an emulator. Are there any specific settings to enable dalvik-vm/garbage collector logging.

Logcat messages I get with the emulator and not with device:

```
07-06 13:37:05.816: DEBUG/dalvikvm(392): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 830 objects / 60984 bytes in 134ms
07-06 13:37:06.476: DEBUG/dalvikvm(392): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 138 objects / 180960 bytes in 141ms
07-06 13:37:09.016: DEBUG/dalvikvm(392): GC_EXPLICIT freed 27 objects / 1160 bytes in 56ms
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even i want to see GC logs . Please let me know if you find one sollution

Answer (score 0):

You could check the logs in logcat while debugging on your device to see what the tag is for those messages; on devices I have got, the tag is dalvikvm rather than dalvik-vm.

Comment: oh sorry. The tag is dalvikvm. How can I view logs with this tag for my device? Does it has anything to do with the property ro.kernel.android.checkjni in build.prop file or log.redirect-stdio. No log with dalvikvm tag is visible in logcat when I test on device.

Comment: Is there any other way to view when garbage collection happens and on what data. Any tool for eclipse? In my app there are lot of GC_EXPLICITS happening in the logcat when I test on emulator. As the GC related Logs are not there when I run app on device, so it is difficult to test.

Comment: theres the DDMS in eclipse which comes standard with the android plugin, which has an heap and allocation tracker.